# Why does cd default to ~?

Tags: bash, cd-command

When you type `cd`, it basically does the same thing as `cd ~`. Why?

I'm wondering if it's just a hard-coded behavior or if bash is expanding the command or something.

Comment: `man cd`: If  no  directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is set to a non-empty value, the cd utility shall behave as if the directory named in the HOME environment variable was specified as the directory operand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the [POSIX specified behaviour](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html). Not bash-specific.

Comment: And it's not only POSIX shells. All shells do, even non-POSIX and non-Bourne ones like csh, rc, fish... `cd` is one of the few builtins that is common to every shell since Unix version 7.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas are there actually any non-POSIX shells still around? besides DOS (and probably powershell)?

Comment: @strugee. As I said, csh (and its derivative tcsh), rc (and it's derivatives like es or akanga), fish, and a few esoteric ones. CMD.EXE, COMMAND.COM and POWERSHELL.EXE are not Unix shells AFAIK. `tcsh` and `fish` are well alive. `zsh` is POSIX-like but not POSIX compliant and is the Unix shell used by most people who actually /use/ a shell (as their main interface to the system).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas yeah, i was being more general than "unix shell" when i said shell. anyway, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't do that under Windows... Bites me every time.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Powershell returns to the user's home directory [when you run `cd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Location?view=powershell-7). cmd doesn't, but it's ancient and has lots of issues due to compatibility requirements, why use it nowadays?